# What is nearest tag in the past and how far we from nearst tag to working directory in Git repository

Tags: git

Mercurial have command to determine if we at tag release or how far from it:

```
hg log -r . --template '{latesttagdistance}'
hg log -r . --template '{latesttag}'
```

Is there a way to get latest tag for working directory and how far we from latest tag for Git?

When I get some GitHub code I usually use tagged version instead of `master` to avoid inconsistent/transient state. I look to list of `git tag -n1 -l` by eyes and this is error-prone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `git describe` gives what you want, by showing the nearest *annotated* tag, `git describe --tags` or `git describe --all` also consider non annotated ones, see the documentation for the gory details.